VS Code terminal freezes after execution of 'flutter run'
As I execute 'flutter run' from terminal, it starts the application properly and I can't type 'r' or 'R' in terminal to perform hot reload or hot restart.
What can be the problem here?
It's getting stuck after the application is launched
Note: By 'Ctrl+F5' the application gets stuck at splash screen. And if I run in browser, it goes fine and give the options for hot reload and hot restart.
